# Removing href from some chidren using jQuery

Tags: jquery, href, children

How can I remove href (using jQuery) only from first 3 Urls?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://jquery.com/">Url1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://jquery.com/">Url2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://jquery.com/">Url3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://jquery.com/">Url4</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work properly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('ul li').find('a').removeAttr("href"); 
 $('ul li:last-child').find('a').addAttr("href"); 
});
```

Thanks in advance, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`:lt`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) (less than) selector to only select the `a` elements within the first 3 `li` elements:

```
$('ul li:lt(3) a').removeAttr('href');
```

Comment: I think you can also use `.removeProp('href')`